# Bar Button Item in header moves logo across in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a logo in Swift 3 with the below code, but when I add a Bar button Item to the left, it pushes the logo across. As below:

[image]

**CODE:**

```
let logo = UIImage(named: "logo") as UIImage?
let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
imageView.frame.size.width = 100;
imageView.frame.size.height = 22;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit

self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

How do i move the logo back into the centre??

Comment: Question edited...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set frame like this for titleView. Change x and y positions as per your requirement.

```
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "test"))
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
let titleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
    imageView.frame = titleView.bounds
    titleView.addSubview(imageView)
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView
```